# I am trying to take a screenshot inside a VM (without being logged in to it)

Tags: virtual-machine, screenshot, rdp, printscreen

If I am logged in through RDP, i am able to take the screenshots. But if i log off, i am not able to take any screenshots anymore as it fails.

I am using python, taking screenshots is a part of a larger script.

I tried using pyautogui but same. Then tried to simulate prntscreen using powershell script but it failed as well.

Finally, i tried to keep the RDP session open, where i used another VM to RDP inside of the second VM (where my script is running)

however, all failed!